# How to compare integer elements in PySpark dataframe array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a schema like this:

```
|-- gs: array (nullable = true)
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | |-- g: struct (nullable = true)
| | | |-- calls: array (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

the last row in this schema is an array/list where there should always be 2 integers, usually both 0.

I feed this into a function, where I compare the array like this:

```
((df.gs.g.calls[0] == 0) & (df.gs.g.calls[1] > 0))
```

which should work as simple as

but this is giving weird errors:

> AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '(`gs`.`g`.`calls`[0] = 0)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`gs`.`g`.`calls`[0] = 0)' (array and int)

why isn't this working like simple python

```
some_list[3] == 4
```

which is array[int] and int?

How can I make a comparison on these integers?

Comment: `gs` is an array, you can't directly do `gs.g`.

Comment: @Psidom how else can I access the values?

Comment: how about this `((df.gs[0].g.calls[0]) & (df.gs[0].g.calls[1] > 0))`?